# Failed import of custom module

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

I wrote a module consisting of 40 conversions, python 3.7. The module is all def statements with triple quoted HELP info at the beginning. When I try to import it, I get 'ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application'. I am at a loss as to what to do.

Tried saving as .py and .pyd. Moved file into every environment on my PYTHONPATH. Multitude of google searches, but nothing I could wrap my head around.

Line 1 is:

```py
def main():
    pass
```

in order to make this work:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But was getting same import error before I added these elements.

import cunvurtz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "", line 1, in 
    import cunvurtz
  File "P:\PyCharm Community Edition with Anaconda plugin 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: Seems like it is something wrong with PyCharm and how you have it set up to run the script. Have you tried simply running your program via the command line: in CMD or Powershell?

Comment: Is there another file with the name `cunvurtz.*` on your PATH anywhere?

Comment: None. I picked the name because their couldn't possibly be a file with that name.